# Maximum input voltage to measure in multimeter/oscilloscope

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, oscilloscope, multimeter

I'm about to buy a [Hantek 2D72](http://hantek.com/m/productDetail/13174) combined multimeter - oscilloscope.

In the specs it says:

> - Input: Maximum Input Voltage 150VRMS
> - DMM:
> - Maximum Input Voltage
>
>   - AC : 600V
>   - DC : 600V
> - Maximum Input Current
>
>   - AC : 10A
>   - DC : 10A

What is the difference between these specs in *Input* and the specs in *DMM*? I guess that the maximum voltage I can measure is 600 VAC and 600 VDC. Right?

Comment: Huh, surprised Fluke doesn't have a patent on the combo multimeter-oscilloscope, what with their scopemeters being the only ones I've seen on the market before now.

Comment: There are two tables stacked vertically which are not very visibly divided into two sections: Oscilloscope mode and DMM mode.

Answer (score 3):

The oscilloscope inputs tolerate up to 150 Vrms, and the multimeter inputs tolerate up to 600 VAC and 600 VDC.

Comment: Ok thanks. So what exactly is Vrms? I guess it doesnt mean that it will break if I meassure voltage above 150vac in oscilloscope mode?

Comment: @acroscene If you don't know what RMS is, I suggest you read and understand that BEFORE getting an oscilloscope.

Comment: Yes for sure. But just for now. Can I use the oscilloscope to see the waveform of something in let say 230 vac?

Comment: @acroscene No, because it's only designed to go up to 150V AC.

Comment: No, not directly, because 230 VAC mains voltage is equal to 230 Vrms. However, if you have oscilloscope probes that attenuate the signal by 10 or 100, and that the probes are rated for measuring 230 VAC safely, then it is possible (not so simple, caveats apply, and think hard about the safety aspects if you really know enough what you are doing to not blow up the oscilloscope or to not get a fatal electric shock).

Comment: In the specs it says: Probe Attenuation: 1X, 10X /// Supported Probe Attenuation Factors: 1X, 10X, 100X, 1000X. So does that basically mean that by setting the switch to 10X it will only pass 23 vac to the oscilloscope instead of 230 vac? So with this switch on 10x I can safely meassure 230vac?

Comment: In general, it should be possible, but you have literally no specs if it would be safe to do that with the probes that come with it - you need probe specs. But yes, without taking probe specs into account, a 10x probe will attenuate by 10 so 230 VAC will be 23 VAC at the scope input.

Comment: I havnt got any answer from Hantek regarding the specs for the probes. Can I just otherwise buy new and exchange the probes with new ones rated for 230 V. Or do I need specific ones from Hantek?